# Running VBS script

Tags: vbscript

I would like to run vbs script.
When I write this in file file_test.vbs

cscript   F:/tp/dir/test.vbs

it does not work.
Please, can you tell me ? with the right solution.
Thank you

Comment: You might want to add a bit more information relevant to your issue here. What is the failure for example?

Comment: "It does not work". What about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include the error you are getting, I'm taking a stab in the dark at this one.

`cscript` is not a command in vbscript, so you can't just toss it in a `vbs` file and expect that cscript is going to know what to do with it. In order to run `cscript` inside of a `vbs` file you'll need to create a shell object and execute it inside that shell.

Something like:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("cscript.exe ""F:/tp/dir/test.vbs""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

But... it seems a little silly to be opening up a shell to execute a vb script that opens up a shell and executes some vb script. Maybe for like testing automation or something?

You can change that wscript shell to cscript if you like to run your cscript inside your cscript.

Also, you spelled csript wrong so it wouldn't have worked anyway.